# Upload and display image form

Tags: html, image, forms, upload, textarea

I store the images in folder.
So how should I ask the user to upload images in the form?

I mean the user will upload the image using the upload button. Then after filling the form,
the user will submit it.
So when I am showing the contents of form again, **how do I check which photo was related to which form** .

Also how to position the image in a textarea?
Should I ask the user to put code `<img src="example.com/images/name_of_image"/>` in the textarea where he wants to display the image?
Is it safe to expose the image path to user?

Comment: My title was upload and display image in form. So two questions one related to upload and one to display.

Comment: What do you mean by how do I check which photo was related to which form? Please make yourself clear. Do you have more than one form? Better give an image or fiddle to support your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I am answering form what I get your problem is. It is always better to write the complete programming part by the programmer and it is always better if the user enters only plain English. In my opinion if you are taking input form a user then use this technique.**I am considering that you have a database and you are confortable using it.**
`1. Take input form a user and ask them to upload the image`
`2. Make a PHP script to store the image in the webserver`
`3. Create a table:`
+----+------------+-------------+
|slno|username|imagename|
+----+------------+-------------+
`4. Now store the image name using $_FILES["file"]["name"]`
`5. You can show your image form the user just by using a simple SELECT command.`
`6. Make sure you have your unique id.`

Ref:[Nice tutorial form w3schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You may upload images into a directory or folder and give it a unique name / number (like PHP `uniqid`). Store this number to the database along with the form data, so that the image ID can be retrieved from the database and shown. In this way, one table row in your database will contain details about a single form only.

Comment: Thanks for the post.Should I ask user to use the code <img src=""> in order to display images according to their position in textarea or is it better that I display the images at bottom of page as default?

Answer (score 0):

To track the images you can have some primary key associated with the name of the image while storing it.

When you are going to display the easiest work around would be to use one picturebox on the form. Initially visible false and while displaying set it to true.